# remove open/save/save as dialog for .pptm (attachmentexecute key Internet explorer)

Tags: registry, powerpoint

to remove the dialog for .pptx the regedit file is this:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
```

"PowerPoint.Show.12"=hex(0)

so whats the command for a .pptm (pptx with macros) please help

thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

I always look that up in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.{FileExtension}

In this case the Default-Key under: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptm is "PowerPoint.ShowMacroEnabled.12" at least for my machine (Office 2010).

I did not test that with .pptm but I suppose that should work since at least that procedure works for .pptx and .xlsx to retrieve the correct key-name.